# What is the difference between a feature source and vector layer?

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, qgsvectorlayer

I'm trying to use PyQGIS to make a tool script in QGIS 3. I'm using the default script template as a starter. The template uses `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource()` to define the input. A quick Google search for 'QGIS feature source' returns links to the [API documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Feature/QgsFeatureSource.html), which is not very enlightening.

What is a feature source?

Why would I use this over `QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A direct quote from the docs for [QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer.html#details) is as follows:

> Consider using the more versatile QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource
> wherever possible.

A few practical differences which you will observe in the resulting algorithm dialog are that with a feature source parameter, there are some nice options available such as running on selected features and run iterating over input features. The image below shows an example of an algorithm dialog using a `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource`.

[image]

You also get advanced options where you can set options for filtering invalid features and limit the maximum number of features processed (see screenshots below).

[image]

[image]

For comparison, this is a test algorithm dialog using a `QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer`.

[image]

There is a lot of good information in this tutorial from Ujaval Gandhi: [Writing Python Scripts for Processing Framework (QGIS3)](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_python_scripts.html)